# Loop on tables with PL/pgSQL in Postgres 9.0+

Tags: postgresql, variables, loops, plpgsql, tablename

I want to loop through all my tables to count rows in each of them. The following query gets me an error:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
        WHERE tablename NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
        ORDER BY tablename;
    tablename varchar(100);
    nbRow int;
BEGIN
    FOR tablename IN tables LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || tablename INTO nbRow;
        -- Do something with nbRow
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Errors:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
> LINE 1: SELECT count(*) FROM (sql_features)
>                                           ^
> QUERY:  SELECT count(*) FROM (sql_features)
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

`sql_features` is a table's name in my DB. I already tried to use `quote_ident()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The cursor returns a record, not a scalar value, so "tablename" is not a string variable.

The concatenation turns the record into a string that looks like this `(sql_features)`. If you had selected e.g. the schemaname with the tablename, the text representation of the record would have been `(public,sql_features)`.

So you need to access the column inside the record to create your SQL statement:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tablename
        FROM pg_tables
        WHERE tablename NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
        ORDER BY tablename;
    nbRow int;
BEGIN
    FOR table_record IN tables LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || table_record.tablename INTO nbRow;
        -- Do something with nbRow
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

You might want to use `WHERE schemaname = 'public'` instead of `not like 'pg_%'` to exclude the Postgres system tables.

Answer (score 46):

I can't remember the last time I actually needed to use an explicit cursor for looping in PL/pgSQL.
Use the implicit cursor of a [**`FOR`** loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING), that's much cleaner:

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
   rec   record;
   nbrow bigint;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN
      SELECT *
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  tablename NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'
      ORDER  BY tablename
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '
        || quote_ident(rec.schemaname) || '.'
        || quote_ident(rec.tablename)
      INTO nbrow;
      -- Do something with nbrow
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

You need to include the schema name to make this work for all schemas (including those not in your `search_path`).

Also, you actually *need* to use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) or [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) with `%I` or a [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) variable to safeguard against SQL injection. A table name can be *almost anything* inside double quotes. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Minor detail: escape the underscore (`_`) in the `LIKE` pattern to make it a *literal* underscore: `tablename NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'`

#### How I might do it:

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
    tbl   regclass;
    nbrow bigint;
BEGIN
   FOR tbl IN
      SELECT c.oid
      FROM   pg_class     c
      JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'         -- system schema(s)
      AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'  -- information schema
      ORDER  BY n.nspname, c.relname
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || tbl INTO nbrow;
      -- raise notice '%: % rows', tbl, nbrow;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Query [`pg_catalog.pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) instead of `tablename`, it provides the OID of the table.

The [object identifier type `regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) is handy to simplify. n particular, table names are double-quoted and schema-qualified where necessary automatically (also prevents [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)).

This query also excludes temporary tables (temp schema is named `pg_temp%` internally).

To only include tables from a given schema:

```
    AND    n.nspname = 'public' -- schema name here, case-sensitive
```

Comment: Seemingly, in Postgre 9.6, `NOT LIKE 'sql_%'` is also (preferably) needed in the 1st example. In the 2nd example, `n.nspname != 'information_schema'` is needed.  Another difference is the 2nd one ignores the temperary tables (due to `pg_%` condition).

Comment: @MasaSakano: All good points, I updated accordingly (with some improvements).